# No packages specified Error when trying to install package from file

Tags: r, windows

I'm trying to install several packages from files in an offline environment.

```
my_dir <- file.path("path", "to", "my", "dir")
my_file <- "jsonlite_1.8.0.tar"

my_file_path <- file.path(my_dir, my_file)

install.packages(my_file_path, repos = NULL, type = "source") # => Error: ERROR: no packages specified

file.exists(my_file_path) # => FALSE
```

What is going on here? I have write permission in the folder. Why does R even claim the file does not exists?

Comment: @Limey Thanks for noting all that, I've edited the question, but obviously, the snippet above is not the actual code I'm running. So these are not the problems.